# How can I get the printed 1 digit number rather than the original number I typed in?

Tags: java

Hello this is my first post, sorry if I asked this question wrong, however, I am also new to Java programming, I am trying to find the largest digit and print the largest digit and continue to print the largest digit (if that makes sense), so the code that I am using is this:

```
    public static void max(String number) {
    if (number.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("The string is empty. Good-bye.");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    int max = Integer.parseInt(number.charAt(0)+"");

    for (int i = 1; i < number.length(); i++) {
        int compare = Integer.parseInt(number.charAt(i)+"");
        if (compare > max) {
            max = compare;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(max);
}

    public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    double weight, temp;
    boolean special, immediate;

    System.out.println("Please enter three numbers for serial number: "); // serial and  msb question
    String msb = sc.nextLine(); // input serial
    System.out.println("The MSB of the serial number is: ");
    max(msb); // determines largest number
```

this does print out the largest number in the sequence, but when I go to print it out again:

```
System.out.println("Item "+ msb);
```

I get the original typed number

If I do:

```
System.out.println("Item "+ max(msb));
```

I get a "'void' type not allowed" error.

The original output is this (I removed most of the unnecessary code):
Please enter three numbers for serial number: 
456
The MSB of the serial number is: 
6
true
What is the weight?
12
Item 456 is 12.0kg. Moved to station 7.

Instead, I want it to say:
Please enter three numbers for serial number: 
456
The MSB of the serial number is: 
6
true
What is the weight?
12
Item 6 is 12.0kg. Moved to station 7.

TLDR, what am I missing or am I not seeing that is preventing me from getting the 1 digit MSB print out?

Comment: `public static void max` is defined to return `void` (or not return anything).  You need to change it so it can return a value

Comment: @oleg.cherednik rewrote my code for me, however, from observing his code and your comment, I guess I didn't really know what void meant until tonight, so thank you I appreciate your help.

Comment: *I am trying to find the largest digit and print the largest digit and continue to print the largest digit (if that makes sense)* what does that mean anyway ? where do you find those digits ? are u talking about digits or numbers ?

Comment: Sorry if the title didn't make sense. But I solved the issue, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it is good practice to encapsulate. So to find `maxDigit` for given `number` (integer or long) it is better to accept it as a parameters and return max digit: `int maxDigit(int msb)`.

Second, you could transfer your number into a string and iterate over all digit to find a maximum, it takes **O(n)** time:

```
public static int maxDigit(int msb) {
   char max = '\0';

   for(char ch : String.valueOf(Math.abs(msb)).toCharArray())
       max = Math.max(max, ch);

    return max - '0';
}
```

As alternative, you can first sort an array of characters, and then retrieve last element array, it takes **O(nlogn)**

```
public static int maxDigit(int msb) {
    char[] arr = String.valueOf(Math.abs(msb)).toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    return arr[arr.length - 1] - '0';
}
```

And finally client method could look like this:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        System.out.println("Please enter three numbers for serial number: ");
        System.out.println("The MSB of the serial number is: " + maxDigit(scan.nextInt()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, so from observing what you did: 
1. Like @MadProgrammer said, you got rid of the void because the return has no value, and so you turned it to an integer. 
2. I see that you used an array to sort out the number, its a lot shorter than my original code, could you please explain the 8th line? (char [] arr = ...) please? (if you have time, if you don't that is totally fine)

Comment: Also, thank you for rewriting the code, I really wanted an explanation of what to do myself, but I guess I learned from observing.